# Getting Flickity images to fit

Tags: javascript, html, css, lazy-loading, flickity

I'm creating a [Flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/) slideshow where the images should fit the containing element so that there's no scrolling involved to see all the image. At the moment I have it so the images fill the available width but you get vertical scrolling.

I've created an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyssen/td414fy8/4/) of what I'm trying to do. I'm also using the [LazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) plugin and using `srcset` and `sizes` with [Picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/), but I don't think the issue is related to any of those as the problem seems to be that Flickity adds a height via inline styles to the `flickity-viewport` element which is calculated based on the natural height of the image, not its scaled height.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="gallery js-flickity" data-flickity-options='{
    "cellAlign": "left",
    "contain": true,
    "wrapAround": true,
    "freeScroll": true,
    "pageDots": false,
    "imagesLoaded": true
  }'>
<div class="gallery-cell">
  <div class="ratio-box">
    <img data-src="http://lorempixel.com/320/238/sports/cell-1a/" data-srcset="http://lorempixel.com/320/238/sports/cell-1a/ 320w,
        http://lorempixel.com/480/357/sports/cell-1a/ 480w,
        http://lorempixel.com/600/446/sports/cell-1a/ 600w,
        http://lorempixel.com/768/571/sports/cell-1a/ 768w" data-sizes="(min-aspect-ratio: 13/9.6) 74.29vh" alt="" class="lazyload">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-cell">
  <div class="ratio-box">
    <img data-src="http://lorempixel.com/320/238/sports/cell-1b/" data-srcset="http://lorempixel.com/320/238/sports/cell-1b/ 320w,
        http://lorempixel.com/480/357/sports/cell-1b/ 480w,
        http://lorempixel.com/600/446/sports/cell-1b/ 600w,
        http://lorempixel.com/768/571/sports/cell-1b/ 768w" data-sizes="(min-aspect-ratio: 13/9.6) 74.29vh" alt="" class="lazyload">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gallery-cell">
  <div class="ratio-box">
    <img data-src="http://lorempixel.com/320/238/sports/cell-1c/" data-srcset="http://lorempixel.com/320/238/sports/cell-1c/ 320w,
        http://lorempixel.com/480/357/sports/cell-1c/ 480w,
        http://lorempixel.com/600/446/sports/cell-1c/ 600w,
        http://lorempixel.com/768/571/sports/cell-1c/ 768w" data-sizes="(min-aspect-ratio: 13/9.6) 74.29vh" alt="" class="lazyload">
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.gallery,
.gallery-cell {
  /* height: 100%; 
  enabling this in conjunction with 
  'setGallerySize: false' means the gallery has no height */
}

.gallery-cell {
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.flickity-slider > .gallery-cell {
  visibility: visible;
}

.ratio-box {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 74.3648961%;
  position: relative;
  img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

The rest of the CSS comes from [flickity.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/1.1.0/flickity.css)

**JS**

```
window.lazySizesConfig = window.lazySizesConfig || {};
window.lazySizesConfig.loadMode = 1;
window.lazySizesConfig.expand = 222;
window.lazySizesConfig.expFactor = 1.6;

(function() {
var oldFlickityCreate = window.Flickity.prototype._create;

window.Flickity.prototype._create = function() {
  var that = this;
  if (this.element.addEventListener) {
    this.element.addEventListener('load', function() {
      that.onresize();
    }, true);
  }
  this._create = oldFlickityCreate;
  return oldFlickityCreate.apply(this, arguments);
};
})();
```

The [Flickity docs](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#setgallerysize) seem to suggest I should be able to set a height of 100% in CSS, but whenever I add a height to the CSS or use `setGallerySize: false`, my gallery has no height.

Answer (score 1):

Try the option `adaptiveHeight` when Flickity inits. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but you can set a height on the parent container (in this case the body) so that the 100% height of your slideshow will actually have a height.

You can see an example here.
http://jsfiddle.net/jm82g4yr/

In this case, I added this css

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately in the complete example I'm working on, the gallery isn't a direct child of the `body`. I already have `height:100%` on the body but if I do the same on the gallery's parent element, it still collapses to no height. I think what I'm going to have to do is write some js to add a height to `flickity-viewport` based on the resized image's height.